# Provider 'myService' must return a value from $get factory method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

```
    app.factory('myService', function ($http) {
    var myService;
    var getData = function(link) { //function to get some data from a get request to 'link'
        $http.get(link)
            .success(function(response) {
               myService = response.data;
         });
        return myService;
        };
        return myService;
    });
```

I am using two controllers,one to send a request to myService to get search results from a search and storing the results in myService and the other controller is of a different page (but same app) where I have to show the results.

The controller below is to get search results and store them in myService:

```
app.controller('headerController', ['$scope', function($scope,$http,myService) {
    $scope.search_it=function(name,link) { //this is called from html, providing the name and link arguments, with link containing the link to get data from
        $scope.respons = myService.getData(link);   
    };     
}]);
```

The controller below is to get data from myService to view on another page:

```
    app.controller("resultController", function ($scope,myService) {
        $scope.resJSON = myService;
    });
```

Where is my problem? And if the code is incorrect then mention where.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a `promise` from your `factory`:

```
app.factory('myService', function($http) {
 var myService = {
    getData: getData
 };

 return myService;

 function getData(link) {
   return $http.get(link);
 }
});
```

Then, in your `controller`:

```
app.controller('headerController', function($scope, $http, myService) {
  $scope.search_it = function(name, link) { //this is called from html, providing the name and link arguments, with link containing the link to get data from

  function getSuccess(response) {
    $scope.respons = response.data;
  }

  function getError(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }

  myService.getData(link)
    .then(getSuccess)
    .catch(getError);      
});
```